HTML CSS full height header
I followed tutorial from this site https://startbootstrap.com/snippets/video-header
it has header style like this
header {
   position: relative;
   background-color: black;
   height: 75vh;
   min-height: 25rem;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}

and I adjust it become full screen height: 100vh;
header {
   position: relative;
   background-color: black;
   height: 100vh;
   min-height: 25rem;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}

It's running well on laptop browser.
But when I open it on my mobile browser, the height is too high over the screen, so it appears as a vertical scroll bar and scrollable.
I want it to be sized for a screen and sticky like it's opened using a laptop browser.

If you're using Safari on your mobile device, the issue might be caused by dynamic viewport height. Try researching svh, lvh, and dvh for more information.

You need to modify CSS code, please try to replace.


header {
   position: relative;
   background-color: black;
   height: 100vh;
   min-height: 25rem;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}



with


header {
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 25rem;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@media (max-height: 700px) {
    header {
        height: 100%;
    }
}



Please let me know if this works for you.

no, it doesn't work. it gives same result.

Could you please share the website URL so I can look into this.

I test it on my localhost, but you can look into this link https://startbootstrap.com/snippets/video-header
